# cyclic dependency error in roblox survival game

Tags: software-engineering, lua, roblox

## Description

In my game, I have have 3 module files: "PlayerList.lua", "PlayerData.lua" and "WorldData.lua".

1. PlayerList.lua = a list of PlayerData classes (requires PlayerData)
2. PlayerData = a table with data related to the player
3. WorldData = a table to keep track of world data and functions that are related to modifying the game world i.e. spawning structures and physical items in

Require path:
WorldData <-> PlayerList <-> PlayerData

`PlayerData` requires `WorldData` because the function `PlayerData:GiveItem()` needs to drop an item on the ground (into the workspace) if the inventory is full.

#### PlayerData.lua

```lua
local WorldData = require(game.ServerStorage.Rojo.WorldData)

function PlayerData:GiveItem(player: Player, itemId: string, amount: number | nil)
    ...
    if inventory is full then
        WorldData:CreateItem()
    end
    ...
end
```

And in `WorldData`, I need to require the `PlayerList` to get the player's information and add it to their inventory:

#### WorldData.lua

```lua
local PlayerList = require(game.ServerStorage.Rojo.PlayerList) -- cyclic dependency!!

function WorldData:CreateItem(id: string, cframe: CFrame)
    ...
    local prompt = Instance.new("ProximityPrompt")
    prompt.ActionText = "Pick Up"
    prompt.MaxActivationDistance = 10
    prompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player: Player)
        -- give player the item
        PlayerList:GetPlayer(player):GiveItem(player, id)

        model:Destroy()
        self.Items[uuid] = nil
    end)
    ...
end
```

## What I have tried

I know this is a problem with my code structure so I have tried moving code around to their own files like `Inventory.lua` but I ended up having the same problem but with different files.

Ex. WorldData.lua <-> Inventory.lua

I have tried using singletons + dependency injection as chatgpt suggested but I couldn't really figure out how to get that to work.

I would like to keep world code and player code in their own files so it's easier to organize and scale my code base as I add more features which is why I have set them up like this.

Comment: I have used the [`package.loaded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899251) approach before to get around dependency cycles in Lua, not sure it applies to Roblox, though.

Comment: `package.loaded` is sadly not a thing in roblox's apis.

Comment: Oh, I suppose it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell what you just did is that you created a dependency with requirements with two different definitions but in two separate dependencies of world data and player data. I think in order to get around the loop of circular dependency is to split the circle entirely from itself and make a brand new abstraction for each world and player data so that one doesn't clash with each other making an error.

After making the first class, PlayerData.lua, which relies upon WorldData then making sure that the second class, WorldData.lua does not convene into PlayerData.lua.

When you run the script I suspect that PlayerData.lua compiles and once it sees WorldData.lua in its line it will try to compile that too. Of course that will cause it to run PlayerData.lua again and then complie WorldData.lua...

My solution to this might be lengthy and time consuming but unless someone with more experience shows us how to use Field Injections I think the best course of action is to delete every dependency related to WorldData.lua and PlayerData.lua and start fresh avoiding that error in the first place. If you need help writing code for getting around that I will keep in check.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by, "making a brand new abstraction for each world and player data". What should the abstraction contain and what should it be called?